# proplem with sdl setup windows

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm a beginner to c++ game development. I tried to set up the sdl library on code block; I followed  every tutorial I have found on Google, but can't get it to work. I also included SDL2_image-2.0.0 and SDL2_mixer-2.0.0 but it isn't working. The error is:

```
#include <winapifamily.h> ||=== Build: Debug in tut (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\mingw_dev_lib\SDL2-2.0.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2\SDL_platform.h|121|fatal error: winapifamily.h: No such file or directory|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
include <winapifamily.h>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Try to remove the include for <winapifamily.h>

Comment: other errors will appear

Comment: Post the code if you want better advice. Without seeing any code it's hard to tell what might be the issue.

Comment: it is only #include <SDL.h>

Comment: `winapifamily.h` is only available in newer versions of the Windows SDK. Either upgrade your SDK or fix your project/makefile to specify an older version of Windows as the target platform. This is usually a predefined symbol somewhere.

Comment: Please, paste more information. `can't get it to work` doesn't tell anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually just set up SDL2 on Code::Blocks myself a day or two ago. Since I suspect your environment might not be configured correctly, here's how I did it, roughly following the tutorial [here](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/codeblocks/index.php):

1. Download both a runtime binary and a development library from [the SDL2 download page](http://libsdl.org/download-2.0.php). Make sure the runtime binary is appropriate for your apps - in other words, if you're building 32-bit executables, get the 32-bit SDL, and if you're building 64-bit binaries, get the 64-bit SDL.
2. Unpack the development library into a folder of your choice, and do the same with the runtime binary. Remember what paths you used for these. I used "D:\Programming\C++\SDL\SDL2.dll" for my SDL runtime binary and "D:\Programming\C++\SDL\SDL2-2.0.3" for my development library.
3. Open your project in Code::Blocks.
4. Go to the Settings menu and click "Compiler..."
5. Switch to the "Search Directories" tab, then the "Compiler" subtab.
6. Click "Add" and browse to the folder for your development library. You'll need to pick whether you're developing for 32-bit apps or 64-bit apps here: if you're going for 32-bit, you'll want to add "\i686-w64-mingw32\include" ("D:\Programming\C++\SDL\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include") and for 64-bit apps you'll want to add "\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include" ("D:\Programming\C++\SDL\SDL2-2.0.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include").
7. Go to the "Linker" tab right next to the "Compiler" tab.
8. Click "Add" and browse to your the folder for your development library. Once again, based on whether you're going for a 32-bit app or a 64-bit app, add "\i686-w64-mingw32\lib" ("D:\Programming\C++\SDL\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib") or "\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" ("D:\Programming\C++\SDL\SDL2-2.0.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib") respectively.
9. Take the SDL runtime binary ("D:\Programming\C++\SDL\SDL2.dll") and copy & paste it into the folder your compiled EXE will end up in. Since you're using Code::Blocks, this will usually be %PROJECT_FOLDER%\Bin\%RELEASEMODE%, where %PROJECT_FOLDER% is the path to your project and %RELEASEMODE% is Debug or Release.
10. Build your project and verify that it works.

You can also set this up on a per-project basis rather than a global basis if you want. Just go into the Project menu and click "Build options..." instead of the Settings menu in step 4.

If SDL still doesn't work after this, I'd suggest getting an updated MinGW and making sure Code::Blocks is properly set up to use it.